# How to set vertical spacing in labeling environment

Tags: koma-script, line-spacing

I want to use the labeling environment as provided by the class scrartcl to layout my CV. I would like to condense the whole document a little bit, particularly the lists in the labeling environment. I am aware of workarounds for itemize or enumerate environments (and the like), however I do not know how to change the vertical spacing of the labeling environment globally.

This is how I changed the vertical spacing for other environments globally

```
\usepackage{paralist} %for the environment compactitem with less space between items
\let\itemize\compactitem
  \let\enditemize\endcompactitem
  \let\enumerate\compactenum
  \let\endenumerate\endcompactenum
  \let\description\compactdesc
  \let\enddescription\endcompactdesc
  \pltopsep=\medskipamount
  \plitemsep=2pt
  \plparsep=2pt
```

And here a complete MWE just to see the difference in the spacing and to clarify my problem (maybe it will be useful for someone at some stage as a CV template too):

## MWE

```
\documentclass[DIV12,pagesize,11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\linespread{1.0}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{nopageno}

\usepackage{paralist} %for the environment compactitem with less space between items
\let\itemize\compactitem
  \let\enditemize\endcompactitem
  \let\enumerate\compactenum
  \let\endenumerate\endcompactenum
  \let\description\compactdesc
  \let\enddescription\endcompactdesc
  \pltopsep=\medskipamount
  \plitemsep=1pt
  \plparsep=1pt

\setkomafont{labelinglabel}{\normalfont}%{\ttfamily}
\setkomafont{labelingseparator}{\normalfont}


\begin{document}

\subsection*{Relevant work experience}
None. Been a bit lazy.

\subsection*{Education and Training}
\begin{labeling}[~]{myheadings}
  \item[2011--2014] Finished Primary School with outstanding success
  \item[2008--2010] Kindergarden diploma
  \item[2004--2007] Learned to walk and talk
\end{labeling}

\subsection*{Additional Skills}
\begin{itemize}
\item Good in spelling
\item Awsum in Math
\item Not so good in creating lists
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

## Question:

How do I set the vertical spacing in the labeling environment?

On top of that I'm grateful for any kind of style advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can redefine `labeling` (as defined in `scrextend.sty`) to include a desired value for `\itemsep`; in my example I chose `4pt` (line marked with `% <- Here`), but you can use any desired value:

```
\documentclass[DIV12,pagesize,11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\linespread{1.0}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{nopageno}

\usepackage{paralist} %for the environment compactitem with less space between items
\let\itemize\compactitem
  \let\enditemize\endcompactitem
  \let\enumerate\compactenum
  \let\endenumerate\endcompactenum
  \let\description\compactdesc
  \let\enddescription\endcompactdesc
  \pltopsep=\medskipamount
  \plitemsep=1pt
  \plparsep=1pt

\setkomafont{labelinglabel}{\normalfont}%{\ttfamily}
\setkomafont{labelingseparator}{\normalfont}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{labeling}[2][]{%
  \def\sc@septext{#1}%
  \list{}{\settowidth{\labelwidth}{{%
        \usekomafont{labelinglabel}{#2%
          \usekomafont{labelingseparator}{\sc@septext}}%
      }}%
    \leftmargin\labelwidth \advance\leftmargin by \labelsep
    \let\makelabel\labelinglabel
    \itemsep-4pt% <- Here
  }%
}{%
  \endlist
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Relevant work experience}
None. Been a bit lazy.

\subsection*{Education and Training}
\begin{labeling}[~]{myheadings}
  \item[2011--2014] Finished Primary School with outstanding success
  \item[2008--2010] Kindergarden diploma
  \item[2004--2007] Learned to walk and talk
\end{labeling}

\subsection*{Additional Skills}
\begin{itemize}
\item Good in spelling
\item Awsum in Math
\item Not so good in creating lists
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code becomes shorter by using the `xpatch` package to patch the `\labeling` command:

```
\documentclass[DIV12,pagesize,11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\linespread{1.0}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{paralist} %for the environment compactitem with less space between items
\let\itemize\compactitem
  \let\enditemize\endcompactitem
  \let\enumerate\compactenum
  \let\endenumerate\endcompactenum
  \let\description\compactdesc
  \let\enddescription\endcompactdesc
  \pltopsep=\medskipamount
  \plitemsep=1pt
  \plparsep=1pt

\setkomafont{labelinglabel}{\normalfont}%{\ttfamily}
\setkomafont{labelingseparator}{\normalfont}

\xpatchcmd{\labeling}
  {\let\makelabel\labelinglabel}
  {\let\makelabel\labelinglabel\itemsep-4pt}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Relevant work experience}
None. Been a bit lazy.

\subsection*{Education and Training}
\begin{labeling}[~]{myheadings}
  \item[2011--2014] Finished Primary School with outstanding success
  \item[2008--2010] Kindergarden diploma
  \item[2004--2007] Learned to walk and talk
\end{labeling}

\subsection*{Additional Skills}
\begin{itemize}
\item Good in spelling
\item Awsum in Math
\item Not so good in creating lists
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very impressive. I know the rules... no thank you etc. But: Thank you! (accepted, +1)