# How to adjust the labeling environment's spacing?

Tags: spacing, lists, koma-script

Is there an easy way to eliminate the spacing between a `labeling` environment's items as well as around the environment, similar to `enumitem`'s `\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep,nolistsep}`? [The only answer I could find to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160920) seems excessively complicated. Then again it was posted back in '14; perhaps there's a better way to do it nowadays?

Example of undesirable behavior (compiled with `lualatex`):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{labeling}{}
\item apple,
\item banana,
\item cucumber.
\end{labeling}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: KOMAScript's labeling environment is spaced out both internally and externally]

Note the spaces between the items, as well as before and after the list.

Example of desirable behavior (compiled with `pdflatex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep,nolistsep}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{itemize}
\item[] apple,
\item[] banana,
\item[] cucumber.
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: The spacing associated with the itemize environment can be adjusted using the enumitem package]

I'm not interested in indenting the list as in the second example, just in removing the spaces from between the items as well as those surrounding the list as a whole.

The reason why I am interested in accomplishing this effect with the `labeling` environment, is that I have already deployed this environment quite extensively as [a way to solve a different problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449972/21685).

Comment: Please help us help you by providing a minimal working example (MWE).

Comment: surely you have been on site long enough to know to provide an example. You don't even say where this `labeling` environment is defined? It is not a standard environment name that I recognise.

Comment: @TeXnician: OK, I've provided examples.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: OK, I've provided examples. `labeling` is build into KOMAScript.

Comment: Btw: You do not need two settings, there is `nosep` from enumitem.

Comment: Ah yes, and `labeling` is a standard LaTeX `\list` environment…

Comment: @TeXnician: So what does it mean in terms of solving my question? How can I globally eliminate spaces from the labeling environment? I don't want this to affect other list environments, such as enumerate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\xpatchcmd{\labeling}
  {\settowidth}
  {\itemsep=0pt\parsep=0pt\topsep=0pt\partopsep=0pt\settowidth}
  {}{}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{labeling}{}
\item apple,
\item banana,
\item cucumber.
\end{labeling}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]